# Where to put Istio network retry

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm very new to Istio and not a Kubernetes expert, though I have used the latter.

For simplicity, say I have two services, both Java/Spring Boot. Service A listens to requests from the outside world, Service B listens to requests from Service A. Service B is scalable, and at points might return 503. I wish to have service A retry calls to service B in a configurable non-programmatic way. Here's a blog/link that I tried to follow that I think is very similar:

https://samirbehara.com/2019/06/05/retry-design-pattern-with-istio/

I have two questions:

1. It may seem obvious, but if I wanted to define a virtual retryable service, do I add it to the existing application.yml file for the project or is there some other file that the networking.istio.io/v1alpha3 goes?
2. Would I define the retry configuration in the yaml/repo for Service A or Service B? I can think of reasons for architecting Istio either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the scalable service is returning `503`, it makes sense to add a virtual service just like the blog example for `serviceB` and make `serviceA` connect to `virtualServiceB` which will do the retries to `ServiceB`

Now, for this to work (from within the cluster):

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: serviceB
spec:
  hosts:
  – serviceB
  http:
  – route:
    – destination:
        host: serviceB
    retries:
      attempts: 3
      perTryTimeout: 2s
```

These lines:

```
  hosts:
  – serviceB
```

Will tell the default Istio Gateway (mesh) to route all the traffic not to `serviceB`, but to  `virtualServiceB` first which will then route to `ServiceB`. Then you will have retries from `virtualServiceB` to `serviceB`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @paltaa. What filename would you call the above, and would you put it in the Git repo for Service A or the Git repo for Service B?

Comment: serviceB.virtual-service.yaml, or serviceB-virtual-service.yaml should be good, and it belongs to the git repo for service B, also kubernetes objects for each microservice should be in another infra/helm charts repo, but you could do that in some next stages